# mysql howto find / debug error "mysqld got signal 11 ;"

Tags: php, mysql

Hope somebody can help here. We're running a MySQL Server (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1), only a single application. A few clients connected pushing and pulling data from and into the database.

Sometimes, it goed all well for a long time... up to hours. Sometime, we're getting errors like

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

or

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away

or

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header

and

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of mysqliConnection::escapeValue() must be of the type string, null returned

Errors above (At least the fatal errors), causes apache to exit with a 500-status-error. Not so good for our clients.

After searching, we found out all are mysql-related. Searching in the mysql-logs, gave us the `mysqld got signal 11 ;`. We're want to find out why this error / signal happens, but can't really find it. Tried a bunch of mysql-settings in my.cnf already, but doesn't seem to fix the issue.

See also these log-lines at pastbin: https://pastebin.com/GWDADudL

How can we find out what causes this error? Already used mysql.log to find out if it happens at a specific query, but seems to be random. Most tables are MyISAM, some InnoDB. Also had a MEMORY-table, but it's MyISAM now.

Help? Please? There seems to be something wrong, but what?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/106323/fixing-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error

Comment: I'd remove and reinstall the MySQL server. Could be caused by an upgrade that didn't work well or OS upgrade, or upgrade without properly running post-upgrade scripts. Or some dependencies that cause bugs.